# The best way to set a key to do nothing

Tags: emacs, mouse, key-bindings

My touchpad occasionally issues `[mouse-12]` events which results in annoying flickering and a repeating `<mouse-12> is undefined` message.

According to elisp conventions, what is the best way to do nothing?

```
(global-set-key [mouse-12] 'WHAT-TO-INSERT-HERE?)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be the `ignore` function:

```
ignore is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.

It is bound to <mouse-movement>, <bottom-divider> <mouse-1>,
<right-divider> <mouse-1>.

(ignore &rest IGNORE)

Do nothing and return nil.
This function accepts any number of arguments, but ignores them.
```

If it's good enough for the `mouse-movement` event, it should be good enough for the touchpad:

```
(global-set-key [mouse-12] 'ignore)
```